# export all variables from EnvironmentFiles

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables

I'd like to export all variables used by a certain systemd service, and are specified in its unit file using `EnvironmentFile`.

E.g. `foo.service` :

```
[Service]
...
EnvronmentFile=/foo.env
EnvronmentFile=/bar.env
```

`foo.env`:

```
a=1
#b=2
c=3
```

So I've thought adding to my `bashrc` something like

```
set -a
grep EnvironmentFile /etc/systemd/system/foo.service | grep -v '^ *#' | cut -d'=' -f2 | xargs  -I {} bash -c 'source {};'
set +a
```

as specified in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761920/165753).

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work at all because you're executing a new bash shell to do the 'source'

Try:

```
load_env() 
{
  local files=( $(egrep '^[ ]*EnvironmentFile' "$1" ) )
  local f 
  set -a
  for f in "${files[@]}"
  do
     .   "${f##*=}"   # this expression delete the EnvironmentFile= part
  done
  set +a
}

load_env /etc/systemd/system/foo.service
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it is using the `source` (`.`) feature of the shell to read and interpret the Systemd EnvironmentFiles (as did the question). But that file has different syntax than POSIX shell (particularly it doesn't require quoting around spaces), and often isn't compatible.